# Json Schema Refs - Use of Additional Properties or Unevaluated properties unclear

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have many objects which have the following properties which occur in multiple places.  Unfortunately, they are not mapped to a specific property but only occur in the body of the JSON object like this: I want to be able to refer to this as a reference but without a specific property as I receive this as such from another application, Is there a way to do this? If you notice I have included a simple case where a person can have a title and occupation and a player can also have an occupation. However, an employee can also have a title and occupation. Since this is common to the person and employee, I want to be able to not repeat the title and occupation fields but just reference them by using the info definition like "$ref" like I did for combining a person and their football team using allOf. Another thing that does not work is unevaluatedProperties: false, which does not prevent someone from adding fields not in person or football_team. Using additionalProperties simply restricts it even more.  In the sample json, party_affiliation should not be allowed.

```
person { 
  name,
  age,
  occupation,
  ... other properties
}
```

Because these properties occur in many objects, I created a definition called common. However, I am unable to use this as a reference in the body of the JSON as a reference. It seems there is no way to do so using something like "$ref": "#/definitions"/common-feature"

```json
{
  "$defs": {
    "common": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "occupation": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": ["Accountant", "Doctor", "Lawyer", "Director"]
        }
      }
    },
    "person": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["first_name", "last_name", "age"],
      "$ref": "#/$defs/common",
      "properties": {
        "first_name": {"type": "string"},
        "last_name": {"type": "string"},
        "age": {"type": "integer"}
      }
    },
    "employee": {
      "$ref": "#/$defs/common",
      "properties": {"name": {"type": "string"},
        "surname": {"type": "string"},
        "age": {"type": "integer"}
      }
    },
    "football_team": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["name", "league"],
      "additionalProperties": false,
       "$ref": "#/$defs/common",
      "properties": {
        "name": {"type": "string"},
        "league": {"type": "string"},
        "year_founded": {"type": "integer"},
        "replace" : {"$ref": "#/$defs/replace"}
      }
    },
    "replace" : {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "appt_kind_" : {"type" : "string"},
        "seen_for_" : {"type" : "string"},
        "seen_last_" : {"type" : "string"},
        "specialty_" : {"type" : "string"}
      }
    }
   },

  "allOf": [
    {"$ref":  "#/$defs/person"},
    {"$ref":  "#/$defs/football_team"}
  ],
  "unevaluatedProperties":false 
}
```

These JSON documents should be invalid but they are not, so the schema does not fulfill the intended purpose. Additional properties can be added and the references do not work as I set the occupation to something not in the enumeration.

```json
{
  "first_name": "Sean",
  "last_name": "Damon",
  "age": 21,
  "name": "Brady",
  "league": "Braonfy",
  "party_affiliation" :"independent"
}
```

or this, which should be invalid:

```json
{
  "first_name": "Davey",
  "last_name": "Mulch",
  "age": 21,
  "league": "Grody",
  "name": "Pullis",
  "science": "danihs",
  "title": "Dee",
  "occupation": "Master"
}
```

Comment: Referencing a definition is common behavior in a JSON Schema. Can you provide more information about what you have tried that's not working?

Comment: I have updated the sample and included the full example. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you should just need to add `"unevaluatedProperties": false` to the end your schema and get to the behavior you expect. Make sure you're using an implementation that supports JSON Schema 2019-09 or 2020-12 as `unevaluatedProperties` is a relatively new keyword and not all implementations have kept up with the latest releases.

Comment: I edited the code in my question to reflect the change you mentioned but it still allows unevaluated properties.

Comment: Yes, I found Hyperjump with   "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema" and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try? what happened when you did?

Did it look something like this?

```
{
  "$defs": {
    "common": {
      "type": "object",
        "title": {"type": "string"},
        "occupation": {"type":"string"}
      }
    },
    "person": {
      "type": "object",
      "unevaluatedProperties": false,
      "required": ["first_name", "last_name", "age"],
      "$ref": "#/$defs/common",
      "properties": {
        "first_name": {"type": "string"},
        "last_name": {"type": "string"},
        "age": {"type": "integer"}
      }
    },
    "employee":{
      "$ref": "#/$defs/common",
      "properties": {
        "name": {"type": "string"},
        "surname": {"type": "string"},
        "age": {"type": "integer"}
      }
    },
    "football_team": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["name", "league"],
      "unevaluatedProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "name": {"type": "string"},
        "league": {"type": "string"},
        "year_founded": {"type": "integer"}
      }
    },
    "info" : {
      "properties": {
        "title": {"type": "string", "enum": ["Mr", "Mrs", "Miss", "Master"]},
        "occupation": {"type": "string", "enum": ["Accountant", "Doctor", "Lawyer", "Director"]}
      }
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
       {"$ref": "#/$defs/person"},
       {"$ref": "#/$defs/football_team"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does but it does not work. I added some examples of JSON which should be invalid according to the schema but are not

Comment: What should be invalid about the examples you provided? And did you notice that I corrected some mistakes in your original? for example, "occupation" needs to be under "properties".

Comment: I noticed that occupation is under properties and that's what I have.  The examples I provided are invalid because they allow additional properties,  party_affiliation in the  first example and science in the second example. Here is a link showing a complete example:   https://jsonschemalint.com/#!/version/draft-07/markup/json

Comment: Sorry the link does not preserve the code

Comment: Yes, your understanding of my question is correct. I am using draft-o7 which has that property. However, it does not work no matter where I put the unevaluatedProperties:false.  Someone explained that since the refs  used in the allOf schema are independent , you cannot restrict the properties using unevaluatedProperties:false or its counterpart additionalProperties. I will try your suggestion to see if it works

Comment: draft7 is too old for `unevaluatedProperties`. You need an implementation that supports draft2019-09 or draft2020-12.